# Block inclusion of a Perl module unless explicitly included

Tags: perl

I have a Perl application which is used in two contexts: It can be used as a diagnostic tool which displays information about a system, or as a testing tool which sends Modbus commands to that system. The problem I have is that allowing the user to send commands to the system in a diagnostic context is a potential safety risk, so I want to create two executables: A testing version that includes the Modbus module and a diagnostic one that does not.

My current solution is to include the Modbus module like this:

```
BEGIN { eval { require Modbus; }; Modbus->import; }
```

This only includes the Modbus module if I use the option -M Modbus while building the .exe with PAR Packager. The issue with this approach is that it fails unless this is the *only* place where Modbus is imported. So if another developer who isn't aware of this risk comes along, it only takes one require statement to bypass this fix.

Is there a way for me to prevent a specific module from being included in the executable unless I explicitly want it to be (either with the -M option or some other method)? I've been trying to figure something out with Devel::Hide, but haven't had much luck. All the solutions I've found so far fail the "other developer who doesn't know about this" test.

I'm using Strawberry Perl 5.20.3.3, but I can upgrade if necessary.

Comment: Could you please supply a small reproducible example of what you are doing. Would help to potentially find a solution for you.

Comment: I'm not sure I can give a lot more detail short of posting proprietary source code. I have a module that can be used to do unsafe things in some contexts, and I need a way to prevent that module from being used in those contexts that isn't reliant on future developers being aware of the risk. Producing two different executables works, but I need a way to exclude the dangerous module that is harder to accidentally subvert.

Comment: Use the power of OOP. Create object if you need it.

Comment: @k-mx I am not clear on how that would help. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I've done this sort of thing, I've created a small module that is included if it is present and not included if it is not:

```
 eval { require MaybeItsThere }
```

In my *Makefile* (or whatever build system you want), I have targets for development and production builds. One of the subtasks for the dev build creates that `MaybeItsThere` file. It can also set whatever it needs for PERL5LIB and so on such that only the dev build can load it.

However, as you say, the enterprising developer can quickly find out what they need to do to get the features they want.

Comment: I'm not clear on how this helps. I can make whatever build scripts I want, but I can't force people to use them. I know I can't protect against deliberate subversion, but I should at least be able to protect against casual ignorance.

Comment: You said you were making executables. The build scripts are for you.

Comment: I'm not the only developer, and I've already had another dev screw this up once. If there's a way for me to have the executable fail to build unless the correct build script is used, that would work too.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but there would be only one build script, and you'd type either `make dev` or `make user` to decide which executable to build. A build script is a single point of entry that manages all of the complexity for you. Behind those targets, you do whatever you need to do to get the result you want.

Comment: Which is all well and good until someone comes along who doesn't know why this is important. As I said, this has already happened once: Another dev imported the Modbus module somewhere else in the code and built the executable with 'pp Program_Name.pl' instead of using the proper script, causing the module to be included when it shouldn't be. Is there a way for me to enforce the proper build procedure, or am I just going to have to signpost this hazard as well as I can?

Comment: So, document your process and enforce it. No matter what you do, you are always going to have to enforce the process. Some other dev could simply require that module in some internal code that you don't know about. That isn't a software thing; it's just a human thing. Apply basic management principles to it and control your workers appropriately.

Comment: "My workers"? I think you're assuming a level of power I don't actually have. Guess I'll have to rely on the documentation. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Having read through your comments, it seems that you're not going to be able to *enforce* correct usage.  (You gave examples how the module has already been misused by people sidestepping your build process.) I would suggest an alternative approach.

*Document the problem **at that place** where someone would find a workaround.*

In other words, if some other developers is going to look at the code or at the build to see the name of the missing module, let them see a warning about the dangers *right there*.  Put a comment block explaining why the `Modbus` module should only be used when diagnostics are disabled or filtered.  Make the build's failure put a warning right there at the same place as the name of the missing module; use a `die "Modbus should not be used when user interaction is enabled.";` or something similar to convey the message in the same place where the other developer would be looking for the solution.

Ultimately, you can't **force** someone to use your build tools, but you *can* try to educate them while they're trying to work around you, instead of documenting the problem somewhere else that they might not see.

Comment: I've already done this as best I can. In hindsight, this functionality should really have been split off into a new tool.